# Rewrite url with an urlencoded parameter

Tags: php, apache, mod-rewrite

I send an [urlencode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php)d address as a GET parameter called `fromurl` to my page `http://localhost/myapp/admin/login.php`:

```
http://localhost/myapp/admin/login.php?fromurl=%2Fmyapp%2Fadmin%2F
```

I would like to enable a nicer URL on the form using `mod_rewrite` which I am quite new to. The nicer URL variant of the example above would have the form:

```
http://localhost/myapp/admin/login/%2Fmyapp%2Fadmin%2F
```

I have tried this line in `.htaccess` which did not work (the URL can not be found):

```
RewriteRule ^admin/login/(.*)$ admin/login.php?fromurl=$1
```

I have other `mod_rewrite` rules working. How should I write the RewriteRule in this case?

Comment: Check http://dracos.co.uk/code/apache-rewrite-problem/ to see if this describes your issue.

Answer (score 1):

Try escaping your slashes:

```
RewriteRule ^admin\/login\/(.*)$ admin/login.php?fromurl=$1
```

Additionally, you might need to add a rewritebase (before the rewrite rule) because you aren't accessing this via a dedicated hostname

```
RewriteBase /myapp/
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, unfortunately it did not work. My other RewriteRule´s work without escaping the slashes or using RewriteBase.

Comment: Is your .htaccess being overridden (by another .htaccess, or a vhost)? Check your <Directory ...> entry and enable AllowOverride if necessary.